# Qt Dropsite Example

Tags: c++, qt, drag-and-drop, qt-creator

In QtDemo there is an example called Dropsite in which an image can be dragged and dropped into the field to be displayed. This example used to work in an older version of Qt and works initially in 4.6 if you run it from qt\examples\draganddrop\dropsite\release folder. But if you load the project file into Qt Creator and recompile it, it no longer displays the image correctly and gives a generic image in the box. I cannot figure out how to fix this and I need to use drag and drop in a project I am working on. Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Drag and drop an image into the drop area, you'll not able to get "application/x-qt-image" in minedata since Qt4.6. But if you drag&drop an image from web page, you'll still be able to see the image. I think it's reasonable for drop area to check if the dropped file is an image or not, instead of depending on mine data.

Comment: I've dragged and dropped an image from my computer and the web and both don't work. In the old version it used to work. How do I get it to work in 4.6?

Comment: in my computer, Windows 7 32bit. DnD a file doesn't work, but image from web (firefox) works well.